# Strategies for proving that a critical point is neither maximum nor minimum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

Let $f(x,y) = x^3 + y^3 -3x$. Since it's everywhere differentiable, we know that its only critical points are $(1,0),(-1,0)$ given that the gradient $\nabla f(x,y) = (3x^2-3,3y^2)$ is zero if and only $x=\pm1$ and $y=0$.

However, $\det Hf|_{(\pm1,0)} = 0$, so we can't apply the Second partial derivative test.

Since $f$ is odd, we might suspect these are saddle points. One way to proceed is to find curves:

$$f \circ \alpha (t) = f\circ (t^2+1, (3^{\frac{1}{3}}t^{\frac{2}{3}})) = (t^2+1)^3 -3$$

$$f \circ \beta (t) = f\circ (-t^2+1, (-3^{\frac{1}{3}}t^{\frac{2}{3}})) = (-t^2+1)^3 -3$$

And it's clear that $f \circ \alpha (t)$ has a minimum at $t=0$ and that $f \circ \beta (t)$ has a maximum at $t=0$, which implies $(1,0)$ is a saddle point of $f$.

But this method depends on one's ingeniousness and it's very time-consuming. I've lost half an hour trying to find those curves!

Are there any other strategies to tackle these kinds of problems?

Comment: One obvious strategy (if you can call it that) is to try simpler curves first. Like going along the axes, for example. For this particular problem, already $f(\pm 1,y)=\text{constant} + y^3$ shows that it's not a local extremum.

Comment: @HansLudmark My textbook says that to prove that one needs to find $\alpha, \beta$ such that $f \circ \alpha (p)$ it's a minimum and $f \circ \beta (p)$ a maximum.

Comment: What book is that? And what's their definition of saddle point? There's some disagreement on what a saddle point is, but the only two sensible definitions (in my opinion) is (a) a point where the quadratic form in the Taylor expansion is indefinite, so that the surface really looks like a saddle, or (b) a stationary point which is not a local extremum, in which case the surface may not look much like a saddle. But just because you have curves $\alpha$/$\beta$ along which there is min/max, the surface doesn't have to look much like a saddle, so that's a weird definition.

Comment: In any case, to prove that it's not a local extremum (which is what it says in the title of your question), you definitely do **not** need to bother finding such curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Finding *one* curve along which it's not a local extremum is enough.